# Fetching old price for InApp purchase price tier

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My app is rejected due to some InApp purchase reasons. Now I have changed the Price Tier for my non-consumable product. And I am testing in device whether I am getting changed price or not.

But still It is showing me the old price in my app. I have not uploaded my app till now.(i.e. again after rejected)

I have set Existing date & End date as "Now" & "None" for price tier

Will it take time to effect or i am missing something.

what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you marked `Cleared for Sale` as `YES` ?

Comment: yes i had mark `Cleared for Sale`

Comment: Then it should display proper price. Make sure you are using valid product identifier. And Have you change app status for Ready to upload?

Comment: Yes i have changed the status & using the same product identifier. It took some time to change the price but i could not recognize how much time it took to effect

Comment: Hmm... So does it working properly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17748/discussion-between-devang-and-roshni)